# Sql Un-Wizardry: Compare values from one list in another

Tags: sql, mysql, list, comparison

I have a comparison I'd like to make more efficient in SQL.

The input field (fldInputField) is a comma separated list of "1,3,4,5"

The database has a field (fldRoleList) which contains "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"

So, for the first occurrence of fldInputField within fldRoleList, tell us which value it was.

Is there a way to achieve the following in MySQL or a Stored Procedure?

pseudo-code

SELECT   *
FROM     aTable t1
WHERE    fldInputField in t1.fldRoleList

/pseudo-code

I'm guessing there might be some functions that are best suited for this type of comparison?  I couldn't find anything in the search, if someone could direct me I'll delete the question... Thanks!

**UPDATE: This isn't the ideal (or good) way to do things.  It's inherited code and we are simply trying to put in a quick fix while we look at building in the logic to deal with this via normalized rows..  Luckily this isn't heavily used code.**

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you want. Can you give some example values and the results that you expect to see? For example, using your given values would the correct result be "1" because "1" appears in both lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Ken White's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826149/sql-wizardry-compare-values-from-one-list-in-another/826170#826170) that comma-delimited lists have no place in a normalized database design.

The solution would be simpler *and* perform better if you stored the `fldRoleList` as multiple rows in a dependent table:

```
SELECT t1.*, r1.fldRole 
FROM aTable t1 JOIN aTableRoles r1 USING (aTable_id) 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(r1.fldRole, fldInputField);
```

(see the MySQL function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set))

But that outputs multiple rows if multiple roles match the comma-separated input string. If you need to restrict the result to one row per `aTable` entry, with the *first* matching role:

```
SELECT t1.*, MIN(r1.fldRole) AS First_fldRole 
FROM aTable t1 JOIN aTableRoles r1 USING (aTable_id) 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(r1.fldRole, fldInputField);
GROUP BY t1.aTable_id;
```

Comment: Confused, isn't find_in_set useful for the denormalized solution?  The question seems to be asking for the *first* value?

Comment: The find_in_set() function finds *one* value in a comma-separated string.  The OP's question was about comparing one comma-separated string to a second comma-separated string, and finding the first match.  Find_in_set() can't do that.  My example uses a normalized table design to help.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  It was inherited code and we are looking at storing fldRoleList in multiple rows... Have to create the add/delete row logic to do that and need a quick fix while we re-work things.

Answer (score 2):

You have a terrible schema design, you know. Comma-delimited lists have no business in a DB.

That being said... You're looking for LIKE.

```
SELECT * FROM aTable t1 WHERE t.fldRoleList LIKE fldInputField + '%'
```

If the content might not always match at the beginning, add another percent sign before fldInputField.

```
SELECT * FROM aTable t1 WHERE t.fldRoleList LIKE '%' + fldInputField + '%'
```

Comment: Or build a temp table and do the usual thing.

Comment: if you were looking for 1, you'd find 11 using this solution

Comment: @Andomar, no. Look at the sample data in the OP - it's a comma-delimited list, and the OP says he's looking for multiple values in a list containing multiple values. Looking for '1,2,3' in a column containing '2,3,4,5,11' wouldn't match on the '11', and if you're looking for '1,' it wouldn't match either.

Comment: It was inhereited code.. Trying to get away from it.  I'm open to doing it another way!

Comment: Looking for 1,2 in 11,22 would find it I suppose. But I assumed the list can contain just one number in some cases